# Autoupdate flask webpage when sqlite database updates

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, flask

The code below is working but in order to get new citys the user need to refresh the page. What I want is when the database updates it should be reflected on the webpage without the user needs to refresh the page.

I did test the *TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=True* but i didn't get it to work.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g
import sqlite3
DATABASE = 'new.db'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

def connect_db():
   return sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])

@app.route('/')
def main():
   g.db = connect_db()
   cur = g.db.execute('select * from pop')
   post = [dict(city=row[0], population=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
   g.db.close()
   return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=True
   app.run(debug=True)
```

The **index.html** looks:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <h3>Reading from sqlite</h3>
  {% for p in posts %}
   <stron>city</strong> {{p.city}}<br>
  {% endfor%}
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need an open connection (either via websocket, or through ajax end points) which'll actually notify your page about those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! Got it working with ajax! Thou now my Client polls the server every 5 second, it works but what I wanted was that the server told the client when it got new information to minimize traffic load on server